# Error while installing go language

Tags: 14.04, golang

I'm following the steps from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480044/how-to-install-the-current-version-of-go-in-ubuntu-precise) to install go.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties  # 12.04
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:duh/golang
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang
```

But for `add-apt-repository`, I am getting the following error:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:duh/golang
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:duh/golang'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

after googling, I found adding -E worked: `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:duh/golang` but I am getting the following error for `apt-get update`:

```
W: GPG error: downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9ECBEC467F0CEB10
W: Failed to fetch <url>/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch <url>//Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

where url = http://ppa.launchpad.net/duh/golang/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It complains about "Cannot add PPA" at the very beginning because this package is not available for Trusty 14.04, see the "published packages" [here](https://launchpad.net/~duh/+archive/ubuntu/golang) of the PPA's page
(It works fine on my 12.04)

On 14.04 there's an official package called [golang-go](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/golang-go)

You can just install it with:`sudo apt-get install golang-go`

Comment: @RedFox  Good to know it works for you, you can close this question by clicking on the checkmark on this answer to accept it, thanks.

Comment: @Lin, it won't let me close it or mark it as answer. I don't have enough reputation.